# How can I efficiently detect all pages with different dimensions in a PDF?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

It's doubtless too unproductive to open ["the Page Thumbnails pane on the left"](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/how-would-I-delete-all-blank-pages-at-once-in-a-document-q162915.aspx), and eyeball each page's dimensions.

In the screenshot below, all pages have the same dimensions from page 575 onwards, but up until this point I've found five that have different dimensions (like page 574).

[image]

Using Adobe Acrobat, is there a more efficient way to delete all pages within a document that are not of a particular size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One "simple" possibility is to activate the Console, and loop through the pages and read out the cropbox dimensions. If you know the correct dimensions beforehand, you can create a list of the pages to be deleted. Then run a command to delete those pages, starting from the highest pagenumber to page 0.

To list the page dimensions, you could run this script:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < this.numPages ; i++) {
console.println("Page " + i + "     " + this.getPageBox("Crop", i) ;
}
```

That lists the page number and the coordinates of the Crop box for every page of the document, which you can then interpret manually.